# Blazor: How to call StateHasChanged after a JSInterOP invoke (try to get the browser resolution to Blazor app after a resize via JS resize Event)?

Tags: c#, blazor, window-resize, blazor-jsinterop

in the last days I'am trying to read out the browser resolution in my blazor app. I'am trying to do it this way: [JSInvokable] Blazor Methode is invoked by a JS script.

1.
My question is: The width and height is only shown in my blazorpage after I reload (manually refresh) the page. I can't call this.StateHasChanged() because my methode is static.

How do I call StateHasChanged or what do I need to do to show the new data? I'am pretty new to ASP.net etc. so please if possible include a code example ;)

Here my Code blazor (serverside) code:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
<h1>Window Dimensions</h1>

<p>Window Width: @Width</p>
<p>Window Height: @Height</p>
<p>@DebugString</p>

@code {
    public static int Width;
    public static int Height;
    public static string DebugString;

    [JSInvokable]
    public static async Task GetBrowserDimensions(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        if (Width < 600)
        {
            DebugString = "small_UI";
        }
        if (Width >= 600)
        {
            DebugString = "big_UI";
        }
    }
}
```

and here my .js code:

```js
//------JS Code for the resize stuff incl. timer so that resize doesnt fire every pixel move
var resizeId;
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing() {
    var width= window.innerWidth;
    var height= window.innerHeight;
    alert('Width: ' +width + '  Height: ' +height);
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Blazor_PageResolutionJS', 'GetBrowserDimensions', width, height);
}
//^^^^^^JS Code for the resize stuff incl. timer so that resize doesnt fire every pixel move
```

2.
Is this a okay technic to get the resolution of the browser in order to make UserInterface design choices?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass the need for this by installing the NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPro.BlazorSize/

If you're still interested in writing the code yourself, you can find the source for BlazorSize at https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize/tree/master/BlazorSize

The solution to calling StateHasChanged from JavaScript involves using a [JsInvokable] method in .NET. However, if you look through the source of BlazorSize you'll notice there is a lot of extra work needed for properly removing event listeners from the DOM once you're through with them.

Comment: Thank you Ed I do appropriate your work very much! I have seen your name pop more then once regarding  Blazor. I'am a little starstruck that you answere here. I literally just watched a youtubevideo with you. Your nuget-package is the perfect answere to the question

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind words. Glad I could help.